# Avoid boolean spreading when creating custom type

Tags: typescript, types

I am writing a library to be used in a React application to interact with a third-party API. To give the responses some structure, I have decided that successful responses will return an object containing a `success` prop set to `true` and a `data` prop of type `T`, while unsuccessful responses will return an object containing a `success` prop set to `false` and an `error` prop set to a key of the errors enum I have defined.

I have created two types, `SuccessfulResponse<T>` and `UnsuccesfullResponse`, implemented in the following way:

```
interface SuccessfulResponse<T> {
  success: true;
  data: T;
}

interface ErrorResponse {
  success: false;
  error: ERRORS;
}

type APIResponse<T> = Promise<SuccessfulResponse<T> | ErrorResponse>;
```

Then, in one of my API calls, I define a function `test` as follows:

```
const test = async (): APIResponse<TestContent[]> => {
  return axios
    .get("<url>")
    .then(({ data }) => ({
      success: true,
      data,
    }))
    .catch((error) => ({
      success: false,
      error,
    }));
};
```

Since TypeScript spreads the type of `success` to a boolean, I get an error because `boolean` is not assignable to types `true` or `false`. I could fix the issue by doing something like `success: true as true` or `success: true as const`, but this would imply quite a lot of work since the library is quite big, and it would make the code much harder to read.

Is there an easier way to fix this?

Comment: pls provide reproducible example

Comment: On which function are you getting the error? Can you provide its typings on your question? [This similar playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogSnA8nAylAvFA5AMwPZ5YDcAsAFDkCWAdsBAE44CGAxtCgK4tsDOPOHADZwIPMHmo8IAHgAqAPigBvclCg8uvHgC4owehwikyagCZNgTXbOMBfclVoNmbWPXp56IsRKnLV6pqiOlDMglLGagwe9LrwSKh2DmSgkFAAggAKAJLe4pIyChhQmR4AtpRS0pzcwQLCovlVRQA+bjF5vhDyxuQC1CzAlBKhBAAUAJS6WbmNXdI8+jQA5ooqJmpQ9BDAHPTUJeWVEAB02zx4ggBuEGPrm5satXy6+oYANAEP5pa6AER-T4bNS2CZJMhAA) has no errors.